# How can I know if some Ubuntu 10.04 packages are still available in Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: 14.04, upgrade, package-management, 10.04, dpkg

I have an Ubuntu 10.04 running on a server. I know that it isn't supported anymore, so I want to upgrade it to Ubuntu 14.04.

I have had problems trying to do this (in a testing environment, of course), because some dependencies couldn't be resolved or some packages couldn't be found (And to be certain, that was from Ubuntu 10.04 to Ubuntu 12.04). **I want to make certain that some packages are available in Ubuntu 14.04, or at least alternatives**, because the server has a lot of applications that need dependencies which are, maybe, only available in Ubuntu 10.04 and when migrated... Not good things are going to happen if I upgrade it and they aren't available.

**What can I do to make certain that all the necessary dependencies are going to be met?** I was thinking about an `dpkg -l` in both Ubuntu versions and compare them...

Comment: Tobias, I'm sorry for my bad english. I'm also looking for a way to determine that. During the last upgrade trial, there were a lot of unmet dependencies.

Comment: Is it correct that you have access to a system running Ubuntu 14.04?

Comment: Yes, I have access to an Ubuntu 14,04

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not exactly a straight answer, but, as you have mentioned, how about you create a list of packages available on both versions of Ubuntu (10.04 and 14.04) and then compare it using *diff*?

You can create this list executing the commands below on each server:

```
$ sudo apt-get update
$ dpkg -l > packages_version.txt
```

Where *version* could be an identification of OS version you executed (like "10.04" or "14.04").

Once you have both lists you could analyze it manually or execute *diff* to check the differences. Something like:
`$ diff packages_10.04.txt packages_14.04.txt`

Comment: I think that's the easier way to do it. I was making a Python script that would take both files and do that. Diff will help a lot in this situation. Thanks for the reply. Also, thanks to all for your attention. Best regards.